# Difference between ACPI CPUfreq and Intel P-State

Tags: drivers, cpu, temperature, scaling

Can sombody explain the exact difference between these two drivers, such as the different options they have and how they differ (for example, in the powersave option)?

Comment: refer [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1hdogn/) and [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/intel-pstate.txt)

Comment: cheers, very informative

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the two good links Ravan gave, see also [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/user-guide.txt) and [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt).

The intel_pstate scaling driver powersave scaling governor is very roughly equivalent to the acpi-cpufreq scaling driver ondemand scaling governor.

Comment: Thanks for that Doug. Would there be a good reason for somebody using trusty to switch to pstate then?

Comment: I thought that trusty was already using the intel_pstate driver by default. I know work is in progress to backport some changes to [earlier trusty kernel versions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1188647/comments/21), but I do not know the status. Regardless, there are still some issues and a great many users disable the intel_pstate driver, thus using the acpi-cpufreq driver instead. All I can suggest, is that you try it.

Answer (score 0):

**Intel PState mode** is Intel CPU thinks he's knowing what system Kernel would to do... It could helpful on MS Dos or GRUB screen (when intel processor is going to max performance and fan is just going to fly away) but not for advanced Linux Kernel.
**ACPI CPUFreq mode** when Linux kernel is choosing default mode and let you full control on your CPU.

Comment: I believe the Intel PState driver is far better than ACPI CPUFreq, because the intel PState driver knows what the cpu can do.